# Spawn 6 windows in 2 rows in the i3 window manager

Tags: x11, window, i3

How can I bind a key that spawns (via the `exec` command) six terminal windows? I managed to figure out how to do this, but all windows were on one row.  What I would like to have is that 3 on top and 3 on bottom.

Like this,

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|         |         |         |
|    T1   |   T2    |    T3   |
| _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ |
|         |         |         |
|    T4   |   T5    |    T6   |
| _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ |
```

This is for the [i3 window manager](http://i3.zekjur.net).

Answer (score 2):

Note this line in the [i3 User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_list_of_commands)

> Commands can be chained by using ; (a semicolon).

So you could first spawn your terminals and then use the appropriate [layout commands](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_manipulating_layout) to set them in the right way just like you'd do interactively.

I suppose you could also use the [IPC interface](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_interprocess_communication) ([in-depth docs](http://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html)), i.e.
`bindsym` some shell script calling `i3-msg` (with some `exec` command) to spawn your terminals (or use [one of the IPC bindings to use Ruby/Perl/C/Python](http://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html#_see_also))