# How do you implement layout with the autostarting of applications in the i3 window manager?

Tags: i3

This is a follow-up on a prior [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96798/44370) on how to autostart applications on individual workspaces with the [i3](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#exec) window manager and what can and can't be done inside the `~/.i3/config` configuration file.

First, the provided [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97081/44370) based on *Arch* Linux [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/i3#Launching_programs_on_specific_workspaces) and an update provided by op where he pushes the logic further:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1:Web; exec /usr/bin/firefox'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec firefox; workspace 2; exec urxvt; workspace 1'
```

Also of interest is this [exchange](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.window-managers.i3.general/161) about leveraging some of that directly on the command line without duplicating:

```
i3-msg workspace 3; i3-msg exec firefox
i3-msg workspace 9; i3-msg exec chromium
```

But I have *never* seen a configuration which autostarts many windows/apps in each workspace according to a desired vertical or horizontal layout. My goal is to autostart this simple configuration I use:

```
 _____ _____     ___________     ___________
| lx  | lx  |   |        |u_|   |     |     |   proportions:
|_____|_____|   |  FF    |lx|   |spacefm    |   1- 25% each
|medit| lx  |   |        |__|   |     | vlc |   2- 75/25 x 25/50/25
|_____|_____|   |________|u_|   |_____|_____|   3- 50/50
      1               2               3
```

So it starts with something like this in the `config` file:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec i3-sensible-terminal; layout toggle split; layout splitv; split vertical; exec i3-sensible-terminal; exec i3-sensible-terminal; exec i3-sensible-terminal; workspace 2; exec firefox; exec urxvt; exec i3-sensible-terminal; exec urxvt; workspace 3; exec spacefm; exec vlc'
```

But how in the world do you achieve the type of layout and vert/horizontal splitting you want? I'm trying, but it's not clear how you "mix" execution and layout. The syntax feels idiosyncratic to start because you're executing `i3-img` within i3's configuration. Do you use `split h` (or v) - `layout split v` - `exec layout split v` - `focus down`(or right) in between each `exec` call??

For a single workspace, the configuration starts all applications either vertically or horizontally and I can't seem to influence layout - or the last `split` command in the chain decides whether the windows are added vertically or horizontally. `i3-msg` seemingly ignores parts of the command that aren't properly formatted in some cases so it's hard to debug. This is further compounded by the fact that you really need to quit X and `startx` again every time to verify the results as just refreshing the configuration with `mod+shift+R` won't cut it even if you close everything on each of the workspaces.

What is the proper way of configuring this? Does anyone have a solution which implements something like that? The [documentation](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html) is pretty good but it  doesn't provide that I can see a detailed example which mixes execution and layout on multiple workspaces.

Comment: Also expands on [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37105/spawn-6-windows-in-2-rows-in-the-i3-window-manager).

Comment: One doesn't need to be using FF or urxvt to provide a solution. There is nothing special about those programs as far as I know so someone could reproduce layout #2 with whatever programs, save a json file, strip it, see if it can be launched from the config file at login, then simply change the program names before submitting an answer...

Comment: can you upload the part in your i3-file in combination with the saved/restored json-layout please? I have the same problem.. but dont get it to work. Do you use multi displays in your config/json file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the *new* [layout-saving feature](http://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html) that was introduced in *i3* v4.8 (2014-06-15). The linked documentation seems pretty thorough.

Quoting from the documentation:

> Layout saving/restoring allows you to load a JSON layout file so that you can have a base layout to start working with after powering on your computer. Dynamic use-cases also come to mind: if you frequently (but not always!) need a grid layout of terminals with ping/traceroute commands to diagnose network issues, you can easily automate opening these windows in just the right layout.

... and the [release notes](http://i3wm.org/downloads/RELEASE-NOTES-4.8.txt):

> tl;dr: export<sup>1</sup> your current layout as JSON file, load it into new i3
>   sessions, get placeholder windows that will be replaced by the actual
>   apps once you start them.

---

<sup>1. You may require the *perl-anyevent-i3* and *perl-json-xs* packages to use the `i3-save-tree` utility.</sup>

Comment: The layout feature is surprisingly challenging to use. Their concept of placeholder window which "swallows" apps means that if you want many times the same app like `lxterminal` or `urxvt` for a single workspace, then you have to differentiate them using `--name something` when you exec them in .i3/config. The example in the doc works but when I use an export from one of my workspace I can't seem to make it work. You use _class_ for the name and _instance_ for what you used with --name. In this case I can only hope for a gui tool seriously, as the _json_ format has so many brackets in it!!

Comment: I now updated to 4.8 and I'm pretty happy with this new feature. I always had some trouble with starting things up reliably at login from `.i3/config` also with earlier versions, but once I'm properly logged in, everything works fine. What I did is to arrange a few layouts and save them, then *only* edit the class variables of the json files. Then something like `i3-msg workspace 2\; append_layout mylayout.json\;` and then `i3-msg exec lxterminal\; exec lxterminal\; exec lxterminal\; exec medit` should restore your first desired layout. // Thanks for improving my answer, btw.

Comment: In case anyone is coming here after failing to start multiple programs in multiple terminals (all the same type) on startup, the layout will not swallow the terminals unless **each terminal is launched with its own title** (e.g. `xfce4-terminal -T program1 -e program1`) and that **title matches the title given in the layout's JSON file**.