# Is it possible to save the state of open terminals?

Tags: terminal, desktop-environment

When working on certain projects, I routinely open a number of terminals, navigate each of them to various directories and resize and position them on my desktop.

Is there any way to save this configuration, so that I can come back to this state easily?

Ideally I would like to save the number of terminals and for each terminal:

- The position on the monitor
- The window size
- The current working directory

I'm using gnome shell, but I am very open to trying other desktop environments.

Comment: What window manager or desktop environment are you using?  The WM or arguments to the terminal program can handle position and sizing.

Comment: @casey, I'm using gnome shell

Comment: You may find interest in [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134980/44370).