# Tiling window manager that keeps the titlebar?

Tags: software-rec, window-manager, tiling-wm

I'm very interested in tiling window managers but none seem to conform to my idea of how it should work.

I have a mouse and I'm not afraid to use it! Most tiling window managers seem to focus on keyboard combinations to get things done.

- I'd like to be able to drag and drop my window into prearranged placeholders.
- I'd like to exit the app via an X button on a titlebar.
- I'd like to resize the tile layout (window sizes) by dragging the window borders around.
- I'd like to see the name of my document in the window's titlebar.

If there's no such thing as a tiling window manager that fits the above description, I would love to have some kind of software running on my floating window manager that I could drag my windows into predetermined arrangements.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: [i3-wm](http://i3wm.org/) does many of these things by default (and the rest may be doable through modification. Have you looked into it yet?

Comment: No. I believe I got halfway through the screencast and all he talked about was keyboard stuff. So I figured it wasn't what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not convinced a mouse-operated tiling WM exists. But i3 definitely allows for it. And, there are plugins to give faux-tiling to GNOME and the like.

Comment: For _Openbox_, make sure to look at [this](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aApplications) and [this](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aAutostart). In the case of _i3_, also take a look at the newest [layout](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140301/44370) features. Most gui apps have their own menu for closing, and something like lxterminal can be right clicked and closed, or I can type _exit_ if I have focus. Using the mouse is not the same thing as relying on window decorations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *tiling window managers* having *non-tiling windows* capabilities.  Maybe the answer is not getting something working out-of-the-box, but using something like `openbox` or `fluxbox` (which allows to use everything you put in your description, and being *mouse-friendly*) plus an add-on or program running on top of that - for example, check the following link:

You might want to try [Tile-windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tile-windows):

> The Tile-windows application is a tool which allows for the tiling of
>   windows within non-tiling window manager.

Also, acording to the [Tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager) Wikipedia's article, there are some tiling window managers that allows the placement of windows in the screen using the mouse:

> **i3** - a built-from-scratch window manager, based on wmii. It has
>   vi-like keybindings, and treats extra monitors as extra workspaces,
>   meaning that windows can be moved between monitors easily. Allows
>   vertical and horizontal splits, and parent containers. It can be
>   controlled entirely from the keyboard, but a mouse can also be used.
>
> **Musca** - features manual tiling, multiple screen support, virtual
>   desktops and mouse or keyboard navigation.
>
> **ShellTile** - tiling window manager extension for GNOME Shell, started
>   from the code of shellshape, allows manual arrangement of windows
>   using mouse and keyboard.
>
> **Ctrlwm** is a tool for automatic window position in various layouts,
>   also processing mouse screen edge/corner actions.

You may want to take a look at the [Third party tiling applications on Xorg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#Third_party_tiling_applications_on_Xorg) section of the article.

So, there's a lot to try - Have fun!